# Copy multiple words individually

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste

I want to be able to copy and paste multiple words at the same time. I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then when trying to add additional highlighted words, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, as in some multiple selection interfaces, but this will not work with Windows 7. Are there any non-software options?

Comment: In wich environment? Actually, it is just CTRL-C to add non-adjacent areas to a selection. But in Firefox, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you want to be able to append to the existing clipboard contents using subsequent copy commands.  It could be implemented by individual programs, or by clipboard utilities, but this is not functionality that is native to Windows.

(Maybe an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) guru has some magic in his hat?)

Comment: +1.  this is my understanding as well.  and since the OP requested non-additional-software options, the answer boils down to a simple "no".